2003 Hummer H2 - Are the upper ball joints and control arms one part?
Trying to press out upper ball joint, but having trouble doing so and trying to figure out which direction the ball joint needs to be pressed out from although there doesn't seem to be much information online on how to press it out on this vehicle. Most people talk about just replacing the whole control arm which gives me the indication that these two items go together as one part.

The ball joint is definitely separate from the A-arm. To remove, you need to press from the thread side. To what you're seeing online, it depends on what your time/effort is worth to you as to whether to just get a complete A-arm/ball joint assembly. In many cases, it makes a lot of sense to go this way. That's what I did on my previous Silverado when I completely redid my front suspension.
NOTE: Part shown is - ULTRA-POWER K6696

